# AWS AppSync GraphQL query a record by a field value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have an user table, which consists of email, phone etc., and I would like to query a record based on its email or phone value (instead of #Id). Having not-adequate knowledge to do this - I wrote a schema like this:

```
type Query {
    ...
    getUser(id: ID!): User
    getUserByEmail(input: GetUserByEmailInput!): User
    ...
}
input GetUserByEmailInput {
    email: String!
}
```

In resolver against getUserByEmail(..), I tried to experiment but nothing worked so far, so its remain to default state:

[image]

So when I ran a query like this to the Queries console:

```
query GetUserByEmail {
    getUserByEmail(input: {email: "email@email.com"}) {
      id
      name
      email
      image
    }
  }
```

this returns an error like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUserByEmail": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getUserByEmail"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 41,
          "column": 5,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxx)"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I query a record by non-Id field value?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Create Resources flow in the console, it will create a listUsers query that looks like the following for example. Note that the DynamoDb operation will be a Scan that has a DynamoDb filter expression where you can use any field to query DynamoDb. See below for the mapping template.

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Scan",
  "filter": #if($context.args.filter) $util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression($ctx.args.filter) #else null #end,
  "limit": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.limit, 20),
  "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.nextToken, null)),
}
```

You can find more details about Scans and filter expressions in the AWS AppSync documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. I found it's more convenient to create a new 'index' to the db and therefore search by that index/field which sort through and returns the matched record. Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that in DynamoDB the filter is applied after the limit.